# Bernoulli equation for $y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the Bernoulli equation.
> Make the substitution $u=y^{-4}$.
>
> $$y' = 5 y + y^5$$
>
> Use the following initial condition: $y(0) = 1$.
>
> $$y =\text{ ?}$$

I simply don't know where to begin. Do I multiply all terms by the $u$? I am not sure how that even helps me fins the answer.
How would one even get the $u$?

The book says the answer is

> $$\left(\frac5{(5+1)e^{-20t}-1)}\right)^{1/4}$$

but reading the answer teaches me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

I would say

$\displaystyle y'- 5 y = y^5 \quad* 1/y^{5}$

$\displaystyle y'y^{-5}- 5y^{-4} = 1 $, substitution: $y^{-4}=u,\, y'y^{-5}=-1/4\, u'$

After substituting we get a linear differential equation.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Ok that kinda made sense but looking more generally. How did you know to multiply by 1/y^5? Is is always based on the last term? (Like would u always be the inverse of the last term? What if it was an x?) Should the last term be the highest power?

Comment: @qwertyqwerty This is a general procedure for solving differential equations Bernoulli - substitution on the linear differential equation. Just look a little theory.